# perplexing python dict.get() behavior with default dict index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

so i've run into a perplexing issue when utilising the dict.get() method in python in conjunction with a default of a dict[index]:

```
d = {1: 1}
d2 = {2: 2}
#throws KeyError
d.get(1, d2[1])
```

i'm a little lost on why this happens....in my mind the `d2` index should never be called, given that the key 1 exists in `d`. I'm guessing this is an implementation detail i'm missing and can't seem to find more info on.

Is there any help/hope for me?

Comment: were you trying `d.get(1,d2[2])`? because `d2[1]` throws an error since there is no key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions used for the arguments to `get` (or any function) must be evaluated before `get` is ever called. Python doesn't have lazy evaluation semantics, and this is part of the language's definition, not an implementation detail of CPython.

Compare this with something like the `defaultdict` type, which takes a *callable* that returns a default value, rather than the default value itself.

```
defaultdict(lambda: 3)  # not defaultdict(3)
defaultdict(int)  # not defaultdict(0); int happens to return
                  # 0 when called with no arguments.
```

`get`, however, expects a value, not a function that can be called to produce a value.

Comment: The first explanation is correct but the second is quite ambiguous. For examle   `d.get(1,d2[2])` works. Ideally, the arguments are evaluated before the function call. Hence the error.  `get` can also take in a function call that produces the specified result as long as the function call does not produce an error

Comment: ahh i see! can you recommend any further reading on argument evaluation? What you're saying makes sense to me but for some reason calling the function like i did in my example felt very....intuitive.

Comment: also, just so i understand--if i were to create a dict-like object, with a method set to provide a default value when the indexing operation is evaluated, i'm guessing that would alleviate this issue? much like defaultdict(int) provides the 0 value when int() is called

Comment: @Onyambu There's no ambiguity; you need to provide an actual value for the second argument to `get`, and `d2[1]` cannot do that if `1` is not a key in `d2`. The arguments are not "ideally" evaluated before the function call: they *are* evaluated before the function call. `get` can take  function as an argument, but it will *return* that function, not call it and return the return value.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? because on my end `d.get(1,d2[2])` works perfectly. It does not throw an error

Comment: @IvanMiller Indeed. For instance, a subclass of `defaultdict` could override `__missing__` to define what `d2[1]` should return if `1` is not a key.

Comment: @Onyambu Of course it does: `d2[2]` is the result of `d2.__getitem__(2)`, which returns a value rather than raising an exception. `d2.__getitem__(1)` doesn't return at all; it raises an exception before `d.get` is called.

Comment: True true, then what exactly do you mean by `get, however, expects a value, not a function that can be called to produce a value.`

Comment: It expects the value to return as-is, not a function that will compute a value to return.

Answer (score 1):

`d.get(1, d2[1])` is not a conditional/branching statement or expression like `if` is, it is just a normal method call, so all of the code is evaluated unconditionally.

Before the `get` method can be called, its arguments need to be evaluated. `d2[1]` is the second argument, so this is evaluated - raising KeyError - before the method is called at all. So this is the expected behaviour, not an implementation detail.

To do what you want, you can use a conditional expression like below, which will only raise KeyError when neither dictionary has the key. The expression `d2[1]` is not evaluated unless the condition is false, because the `if` expression branches.

```py
d[1] if 1 in d else d2[1]
```